Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin iOS Binding Library build succeeds but dll is empty
I created an iOS Binding Library with several frameworks and implemented ApiDefinition.cs.
Building the project completes (successfully) immediately and the resulting dll is only 4kb in size.

Similar issue described here suggests the issue is fixed in VS 2019, but issue occurs on VS 2022.
Interestingly enough, ApiDefinition.cs content is completely ignored, even though the build action is ObjcBindingApiDefinition. The file can contain any content and the build will still succeed.


Well, I would love to see an error instead of a successful build with empty output, but apparently this is what you get when the Mac is not connected to Visual Studio.
As soon as Mac Pairing completes, the output dll contains the frameworks and the binding of ApiDefinition
